# streamwriter doesn't save all the listview items to text file

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, streamwriter.write

so im using this code to save my listview items into a text file:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.InitialDirectory = Application.ExecutablePath;
        sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        sfd.Title = "Save Text file";
        sfd.FileName = "log";
        DialogResult result = sfd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        StreamWriter wwrite = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 14738; ++i)
        {
            wwrite.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "|" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + "|" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + "|" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
        }
```

as you can see my listview item count is up to 14738:
[image: listview item count]
but the text file only saved up to 14678 (including the line number 0):
[image: line where it stops]

i get no error or exception, and i don't think my code is wrong, i've used it many other times, the result was always perfect, i even used it on a listview of more than 32000 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your streamwriter is actually writing everything in the buffer before it closes. You can do this with either

```
wwrite.Flush()
```

or by wrapping your streamwriter in a using block. Disposing of a Streamwriter automatically flushes its buffer. Change your code to

```
using (StreamWriter wwrite = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS")))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 14738; ++i)
    {
        wwrite.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "|" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + "|" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + "|" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer, i wraped it with a using block, made it save faster.

Comment: @Omarrrio a using block is very useful for instances like this where you're using your streamwriter for a single, simple thing. If you're ever using a streamwriter for multiple operations, flush is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the `StreamWriter` in a [using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)? I suspect disposing of it will clear any buffers and you'll get all the data.

(edit) or you could [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) `Flush` on the StreamWriter. As StreamWriter is `IDisposable` [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you really should dispose any instances of it properly.